# Azure SDK for C IoTHub client fails to get clientID for device ID's in certain format

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-sdk

I am using the Azure SDK for C and I am trying to connect a device to IoTHub. I noticed that I can connect with no issues if I use a device ID like this `"testDevice"`. But if I use something like this `"11:11:11:11:11:11"` it fails to connect via mqtt. I have made sure that both devices exist in azure IoTHub and I have updated the connection strings for both when changing them. I have come to the conclusion that, although azure allows me to create a device with these characters, the SDK is having issues connecting to it. Here is what I am doing...

```
String uuid = "11:11:11:11:11:11"; // this one fails
String uuid = "testingDevice"; // this one works
static const char* device_id = uuid.c_str();
```

The client is connecting fine but the below chunk is returning the failed string to the serial. No errors though.

```
  char mqtt_username[128];
  // Get the MQTT user name used to connect to IoT Hub
  if (az_result_failed(az_iot_hub_client_get_user_name(
          &client, mqtt_username, sizeofarray(mqtt_username), NULL)))
  {
    printf("Failed to get MQTT clientId, return code\n");
    return 1;
  }
```

And the reason I am using this format for a device_id is simply because this is a mac address which is unique to a device.

Comment: If anyone finds a solution, please post. In the mean time I simply took out the colons and it is working fine. I could expiriment with replacing the colons with some special char until it works as well. It would remain just as unique this way.

Comment: Pick one C or C++?

Comment: One possible solution is to remove the colons from the device ID before passing it to the Azure SDK. You can use a regular expression to replace any colons in the device ID with another character, such as an underscore.

Comment: @Sourav This is what I ended up doing. Easy solution but not sure why colons wouldn't work. The api call uses it in the url, so maybe this is why.

Comment: In my case underscores caused the same problem. I guess device IDs must be alphanumeric?